# Stoping and restarting embedded Tomcat8 fails with port already in use

Tags: java, kotlin, tomcat

I have java (kotlin) app starting multiple embedded servers. That's allright. I have also few unit tests, which starts these servers before each unit and stops them after.

The stop method on tomcat finishes with no exception, but consequent server start starts fails with port is in use.

My base class is pretty standard

```
open class TomcatBase(
    val tomcat: Tomcat = Tomcat()
) {
    val context:Context
    val contextPath:String

    init {
        tomcat.engine.name=UUID.randomUUID().toString()
        contextPath = ""
        val dir_url: URL = ClassLoader.getSystemResource("static")
        val docBase = File(dir_url.toURI()).absolutePath
        context = tomcat.addContext(contextPath, docBase)
    }

    fun addServlet(path: String, servlet: Servlet) {...}

    fun start() {
        tomcat.start()
        context.resources.isCachingAllowed = false
    }

    fun stop() {
        tomcat.stop()        
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Turns out that there's also destroy() method, which does the job

```
fun stop() {
        tomcat.stop()
        tomcat.destroy()
    }
```